# zsh tmux powerline multiple lines, normal operation

Tags: zsh, tmux, powerline

This is my `.tmux.conf`

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
set -g mode-mouse on

# use UTF8
set -g utf8
set-window-option -g utf8 on

shell "powerline-daemon -q"
source "/Users/lighter/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf"

 ~ > python --version
Python 2.7.10
 ~ > pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
 ~ > vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 16 2015 15:31:56)
```

And When I type `tmux`, I can't normal operation, and jump multiple lines powerline. How can I fix it. I have search a lot, but not work for me. Thanks your help.

[image]

Comment: When this happens to me (and it does rarely), I just restart tmux (and the terminal session it uses) and it's OK.

Comment: I restart a lot, and it's same.

Comment: i'm having the same issue on fedora 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add LANG setting in your zshrc like `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Next, If you use iTerm2, try below.

iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Text
Uncheck "Treat ambiguous-width characters as double width" at "Double-Width Characters".

Or Terminal.app, try this.

Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced
Uncheck "Unicode East Asian Ambiguous characters are wide" at "International".

I think that will resolve problem, but may cause another problem if you use CJK language.

For example, vim in tmux, non-ascii characters ("☆", "※", "♪" ...) would be treat as ascii.
To avoid this, you have to patch tmux with [these gist](https://gist.github.com/waltarix/1399751).
After that, Check these above unchecked options, it will work fine :)